# Trouble with container height = 100% not working - Angular/Material

Tags: html, css, angular, flexbox, angular-material2

I am creating a mockup for a new UI using Angular and Material design elements, however I am experiencing trouble attempting to get the area underneath my toolbar to take up the remaining vertical height of the page.

[Here is a link to my code example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/australia-greyhounds-ui-material-stackoverflow)

I have Googled the problem and the only thing I have seen is the solution to set

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

However I have not found this to be a solution.
I was thinking of perhaps using a flex box, but I am unfamiliar with how they are used.

Any help would be appreciated.

**UPDATES & SOLUTION**
I opted not to go the flexbox route as I was wanting something quick as a solution and flexbox can be something I look more into in the future.

After deciding that I wanted a static nav bar, of which was not occurring when first coded, I set upon using a CSS calculation to utilise `height: 100vh` and subtract the overhang that this caused.

```
mat-sidenav-container {
    height: calc(100vg - 64px);
}
```

I found however, that when shrinking the size of the window, the responsive nature of the material elements meant that the toolbar would reduce in height somewhat. This led to a blank bar below the page content as the amount to subtract would need to be less in this situation.

The fix for this was to add an `@media` change for the specific page width the shrinking is triggered. I was then eventually left with the following:

```
mat-sidenav-container {
  height: calc(100vh - 64px);
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    mat-sidenav-container {
        height: calc(100vh - 56px)
    }
}
```

This may not be the best solution for the problem, but so far I have found this to be one solution that works.

Comment: `I was thinking of perhaps using a flex box, but I am unfamiliar with how they are used` Flexbox can definitely achieve this. But we're not going to develop the solution for you! You need to give it a go first.

Comment: The problem is that you are setting some divs to `position:absolute`. By doing this, you kind of "detach" them from their parent container, which collapses to 0 height (or to the height of its other children, if any). You just won't be able to achieve a structured layout with elements in `position:absolute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is what worked for me in with the code you gave me:

I added the `style="height:100%"` to the following classes:

`html`, `blitz-app`, to the secondary `div` and to the `mat-sidebar-container`

Edited: Changed the style of the `html` tag to: `height:calc(100% - 64px);`
Reason: the 64px is the height of the toolbar

[image: See image]

I added it all in the chrome browser debugging console, because I couldn't find the actual classes the code is using, but I am sure you can :)

Hope I could help.

Comment: I managed to get what you had done working, thank you. However, I have the problem now of the drawer being too tall and causing a scrollable region off of the page?

Comment: You can see the vertical scrollbar on your image in fact!

Comment: aha, gimme a moment

Comment: All I want is a static nav bar the doesn't scroll with the page content - and for that navbar to be full height below the toolbar... why do they make these things so difficult when every single app ever is designed this way? XD

Comment: I just edited the code, see if it helps, and yes, you are right, why should that be easy if it can be difficult? :)

Comment: Could you provide a link? Fork the code also if you are editing mind :P

Comment: I edited my answer, just add the height:calc(100% - 64px); instead of the height:100% in the html tag, and I cannot add the link, bc I run the link that you gave me on the debugging chrome console, there cannot be saved anything, and if i send you the same link as you gave me, my changes will disapear

Comment: Aha, I am with you. I actually just implemented that about 1 minute before you posted! Great minds... ;-). However I have found that the toolbar at the top with "Australian Greyhounds" in actually shrinks slightly when the window is narrowed due to responsive design etc. leaving a bar at the bottom - Not the end of the world as this will mainly be used as a full screen app.

Comment: I actually solved my little problem of the re-scaling at small sizes by adding:

@media (max-width: 600px) {
    mat-sidenav-container {
        height: calc(100vh - 56px)
    }
}

Comment: Nice, add it to the question, for the  next guy who comes around.

Comment: Boom. Added to the original question